# Unexpected outcome Php

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to subtract two variables from other methods here is  what I have I
 feel like the should work No idea why it it's working.

```
    public function GetM(){

       $q = $this->Cycle();
       $qq =$this->SageData();

       $this->M = $q - $qq ;

        echo $this->M;
```

when i run this i get there is an echo in each of the called methods so 135.0 is cycle    428.4 is SageData and result of the subtraction  0  however the expected result should be -293.4 why is this?

Comment: Does `$this->Cycle()` **echo** 135.0 or does it **return** 135.0?

Comment: $this->Cycle() and $this->SageData() both echo should they return instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem you're facing has to do with getting values out of a function. To get a value from a function so that you can set a variable to it, you want to use the [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement. You can modify your Cycle and SageData to look something like this:

```
public function Cycle() {
    $toRet = 135.0;

    // ...snip
    return $toRet;
}
```

Comment: To further clarify it, as the methods don't return anything, PHP considers it is "0". So 0 - 0 = 0.

Comment: Thank you for the help Returning instead of Echo fixed it.